# Device id is not passed to Azure AD with MS Intune (error we are getting error Set Up your device to get access) in Electron App

Tags: azure, electron, electron-builder, azure-compliance-policy

Developers

I am using Electron application, where we have Single Sign On (SSO) functionality in which we are redirecting Microsoft azure URL.

Here the problem is, it's working for in normal scenario where no "**compliance policy**" under network.

Now we have applied "**compliance policy**" where it fetches device id. If device id is found it works properly else it will show restriction message as shown in the below image.

[image]

While **same URL we use in browser it works properly (as I guess browser is sharing that needed device ID)**, here in Azure Policy portal we found that calling through browser device id is showing while in Electron app it is not. **If it will pass that device ID it can work**

**I am unable to find out HOW I can find and share that device ID?**

I have tried the same in Electron page with Browser Window and WebView as well but it does not work in either.

Comment: Did you managed to find the solution. I might be having similar issue, but my Integration for third party app does not provide Device ID to azure when not in corporate network.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome uses the Windows Accounts extension to provide the device ID to Azure. Since Chrome 111 there is a new functionality that also provides the device ID if  the registry key [CloudAPAuthEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/conditional-access/concept-conditional-access-conditions#chrome-support) is set.

At the moment electron does not support this registry key but there is already an issue for this: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/40721